# Check multiple columns data format and append results to one column in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a toy dataset as follows:

```
   id    room   area           situation
0   1   A-102  world  under construction
1   2     NaN     24  under construction
2   3    B309    NaN                 NaN
3   4   C·102     25    under decoration
4   5  E_1089  hello    under decoration
5   6      27    NaN          under plan
6   7      27    NaN                 NaN
```

I need to check three columns: `room, area, situation` based on the following conditions:

(1) if `room` name is not number, alphabet, `-` (`NaN`s are also considered as invalid one), then returns `incorrect room name` for `check` column;

(2) if `area` is not `number` or `NaN`s, then returns and appends `area is not numbers` to the existing `check` column.

(3) if `situation` has `under decoration`, then returns and appends `decoration is in the content` to the existing `check` column.

Please note I have other columns to check in real data and I need to append new `check` results by seperators `;`.

How could I get the **expected result** like this:

```
   id    room   area           situation                                              check
0   1   A-102  world  under construction                                area is not numbers
1   2     NaN     24  under construction                                                incorrect room name
2   3    B309    NaN                 NaN                                                NaN
3   4   C·102     25    under decoration  incorrect room name; decoration is in the content
4   5  E_1089  hello    under decoration  incorrect room name; area is not numbers; decoration is in the content
5   6      27    NaN          under plan                                                NaN
6   7      27    NaN                 NaN                                                NaN
```

My code so far:

Room name check:

```
df['check'] = np.where(df.room.str.match('^[a-zA-Z\d\-]*$'), np.NaN, 'incorrect room name')
```

Out:

```
   id    room   area           situation                check
0   1   A-102  world  under construction                  nan
1   2     NaN     24  under construction                  nan
2   3    B309    NaN                 NaN                  nan
3   4   C·102     25    under decoration  incorrect room name
4   5  E_1089  hello    under decoration  incorrect room name
5   6      27    NaN          under plan                  nan
6   7      27    NaN                 NaN                  nan
```

Area check:

```
df['check'] = df['check'].where(df.area.str.contains('^\d+$', na = True),
                                'area is not a numbers')
```

Out:

```
   id    room   area           situation                  check
0   1   A-102  world  under construction  area is not a numbers
1   2     NaN     24  under construction                    nan
2   3    B309    NaN                 NaN                    nan
3   4   C·102     25    under decoration    incorrect room name
4   5  E_1089  hello    under decoration  area is not a numbers
5   6      27    NaN          under plan                    nan
6   7      27    NaN                 NaN                    nan
```

Situation check:

```
df['check'] = df['check'].where(df.situation.str.contains('under decoration', na = True),
                                'decoration is in the content')
```

Out:

```
   id    room   area           situation                         check
0   1   A-102  world  under construction  decoration is in the content
1   2     NaN     24  under construction  decoration is in the content
2   3    B309    NaN                 NaN                           nan
3   4   C·102     25    under decoration           incorrect room name
4   5  E_1089  hello    under decoration         area is not a numbers
5   6      27    NaN          under plan  decoration is in the content
6   7      27    NaN                 NaN                           nan
```

Thanks.

Comment: So is your question "how to join the results of the 3 checks into one column?"

Comment: Yeah, you can understand in that way, after they (`check1, check2, check3, etc.`) are joined together to `check`, then delete `check1, check2, check3, ...`  Also, I don't know why `situation` check give us wrong answer.

Comment: Or maybe we can rewrite a function code since there are may columns and conditions to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First was changed output from each test by [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), then `zip` each array and apply custom function for join if no missing value:

```
a = np.where(df.room.str.match('^[a-zA-Z\d\-]*$', na = False), None,
                               'incorrect room name')
b = np.where(df.area.str.contains('^\d+$', na = True), None,
                                 'area is not a numbers')  
c = np.where(df.situation.str.contains('under decoration', na = False),
                                      'decoration is in the content', None) 


f = (lambda x: ';'.join(y for y in x if pd.notna(y)) 
                if any(pd.notna(np.array(x))) else np.nan )
df['check'] = [f(x) for x in zip(a,b,c)]
print(df)
   id    room   area           situation  \
0   1   A-102  world  under construction   
1   2     NaN     24  under construction   
2   3    B309    NaN                 NaN   
3   4   C·102     25    under decoration   
4   5  E_1089  hello    under decoration   
5   6      27    NaN          under plan   
6   7      27    NaN                 NaN   

                                               check  
0                              area is not a numbers  
1                                incorrect room name  
2                                                NaN  
3   incorrect room name;decoration is in the content  
4  incorrect room name;area is not a numbers;deco...  
5                                                NaN  
6                                                NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but for `id` is `6`, the `check` result also gives `decoration is in the content`, in fact, it's `under plan`.

Comment: No, my code gives wrong answer, but i dont know why. Also, the first condition didn't return `incorrect room name` when room name is `NaN`. Sorry for this complicated logic.

Comment: @ahbon - How looks expected output? I first think each conditon working well, so not?

Comment: @ahbon - Thanks, I think now it should working correct.

Comment: I've posted the expected result in the question. Also, the third row seems don't have `seperator`.

Answer (score 1):

I reworked your conditions a bit so the result comes closer to your expected output:

```
a = np.where(df.room.str.match('^[a-zA-Z\d\-]*$').notnull(), pd.NA, 'incorrect room name')
b = np.where(df["area"].str.isnumeric() & df["area"].notnull(), pd.NA, 'area is not a numbers')
c = np.where(df.situation.str.contains('under decoration', na = False), 'decoration is in the content', pd.NA)

s = (pd.concat([pd.Series(i, index=df.index) for i in (a, b, c)], axis = 1)
       .stack().groupby(level = 0).agg("; ".join))

print(df.assign(check=s))

   id    room   area           situation                                              check
0   1   A-102  world  under construction                              area is not a numbers
1   2     NaN     24  under construction                                incorrect room name
2   3    B309    NaN                 NaN  area is not a numbers; decoration is in the co...
3   4   C·102     25    under decoration                       decoration is in the content
4   5  E_1089  hello    under decoration  area is not a numbers; decoration is in the co...
5   6      27    NaN          under plan                              area is not a numbers
6   7      27    NaN                 NaN  area is not a numbers; decoration is in the co...
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Rameez PC\Desktop\python data files 2\")

extension = 'xlsx'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

#combine all files in the list
combined_xlsx1 = pd.concat([pd.read_excel(f) for f in all_filenames] )
#export to csv
combined_xlsx1.to_excel( "combined.xlsx", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood what I need.