# Filter desired characters as substring of one column but not the whole strings in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a small dataset as follows:

```
   id                        company
0   1                Reichel-DuBuque
1   2                       Jast LLC
2   3                    Strosin LLC
3   4   O'Connell, Ortiz and Ullrich
4   5                            LLC
5   6                            Ltd
6   7  Schoen, Bauch and Breitenberg
7   8                      Doyle Ltd
```

I want to filter out the rows which `LLC` or `Ltd` is substrings but not the whole strings, how could I do that? `df[df.company.str.contains('LLC|Ltd')]` gives me:

```
   id      company
1   2     Jast LLC
2   3  Strosin LLC
4   5          LLC
5   6          Ltd
7   8    Doyle Ltd
```

But I needed is like this:

```
   id      company
1   2     Jast LLC
2   3  Strosin LLC
7   8    Doyle Ltd
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain another mask for test not equal with `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
df = df[df.company.str.contains('LLC') & df.company.ne('LLC')]
print(df)
   id      company
1   2     Jast LLC
2   3  Strosin LLC
```

**Details**:

```
print (dd.company.str.contains('LLC'))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: company, dtype: bool

print (dd.company.ne('LLC'))
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
Name: company, dtype: bool
```

EDIT:

```
df = df[df.company.str.contains('LLC|Ltd') & ~df.company.isin(['LLC', 'Ltd'])]
print (df)
   id      company
1   2     Jast LLC
2   3  Strosin LLC
7   8    Doyle Ltd
```

Comment: Thanks, if it's multiple characters (`LLC, ltd.`) need to match, then I should use: `df[df.company.str.contains('LLC|ltd.') & df.company.ne(['LLC', 'ltd.'])]`, right?

Comment: @ahbon - For second use `~df.company.isin(['LLC', 'ltd.'])`

Comment: @ahbon - It semes typo `ltd.` with `Ltd`

Comment: Do you mind have a look this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64852384/filter-nan-rows-for-containing-specific-characters-columns-in-pandas. I want to use `np.where` if it's possible.

Comment: @a - Hmm, so need new mask for all columns? change `highlight(x)` to `df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df.filter(like='*').isna(), '', c1), index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns)`

Comment: It raises error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df1' referenced before assignment`

Comment: @ahbon - Add code before `return` after `df1['situation'] = np.where(m3, c1, '')`

Comment: It raises `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (10, 234), indices imply (25, 234)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224618/discussion-between-jezrael-and-ahbon).